# How to properly update an array in functional React with useState

Tags: arrays, reactjs, use-state

I've waded all over StackOverflow and Google, and I've been unable to find a solution for the following, so all help would be appreciated.

Let's suppose I am using the useState hook in react, and I've defined an element of state thusly:

`const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState([]);`

Let's further suppose that I want to update this array with an array of objects, such that the resulting array will be an array of all of the objects I want to push into it.  So, let's suppose I tried this:

```
let newItems = [...selectedItems];
newItems.push({a complex object});
setSelectedItems(newItems);
```

selectedItems will remain `[]`.

I have tried a half dozen different permutations on how to set this state, and have not found success.  With everything I do, selectedItems always remains `[]`.

I have a need to both push objects into this array, and also to remove them... but I would be happy to simply replace the entire array.  The problem is that I cannot find how to update this array in state if I am using functional React and the useState hook.  As I said, if update like  `setSelectedItems([new array of objects])` then state doesn't change.

I know similar questions to this have been asked multiple times on StackOverflow, but I could not find any example directly comparable to this use case.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *selectedItems will remain []* It really shouldn't - that should result in a re-render, with a new value for `selectedItems`. Can you post a [MCVE] illustrating the problem?

Comment: I'm assuming you've verified that your update function is being called? And that `newItems` contains what you expect?

Comment: I have added a minimal demo to my answer, feel free to play with it to get a feeling for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the old state in the setter method by defining an anonymous function, e.g.

```
const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState([]);

setSelectedItems((oldItems) => [...oldItems, yourNewItem])
```

No need to deconstruct and add a new item via push, espacially if you want to be functional.

The render method will update your view, when you properly iterate over it and use keys to tell React, which objects are which.

EDIT: To prove this is working, here is a working demo. If it is not working for you like this, you may have used your array in a way, where react can't tell the difference between the arrays, so there will be no rerender visible.

```js
const Demo = () => {
    
    const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = React.useState(["a", "b", "c"]);
    
  const removeItem = (item) => {
    setSelectedItems((oldItems) => [
        ...oldItems.filter(i => i !== item), 
      `Removed item ${item}`
    ])
  }
  
  return (<div>
    {selectedItems.map(item => <button key={"item-"+item}
      onClick={() => removeItem(item)}>Remove Item {item}</button>)} 
  </div>);

}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I didn't -1 this, but this doesn't work.  The array remains [];

Answer (score 0):

**Reposting the answer because the link in the earlier answer wasn't working**

You can try something like this

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([])

let updatedList = [...items, ...moreItems]
setItems(updatedList)
```

Where "moreItems" is again an array of objects. If you want to add a single object, you can try this

```
let updatedList = [...items, {key : 'value'}]
setItems(updatedList)
```

Check this link with a working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6enrwj

Comment: Could you share more of your code to understand in what case your array is getting empty?